# WebSocket connection established, onopen never runs

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to learn WebSockets and I've created a websocket server in Node and am now working on the browser implementation. I have tested that the server works and responds how I want using a chrome extension called Smart WebSocket Client.

The console in the browser says `Button pressed!` when you press the button and `Connection lost! (1000)` when I end the Node process but never has it said `Connection Established!`.

**Edit:** The client code is running on a site secured with HTTPS and that serves the HSTS header while the server code (currently, but won't continue to be) is running on localhost over normal HTTP, if it's any concern.

Server Code:

```
const websock = require('./node_modules/ws');
const HashMap = require('./node_modules/hashmap');
const jsonparse = require('./node_modules/jsonparse');
const randomstring = require('./node_modules/randomstring');

class Session {
    constructor(server) {
        this.server = server;
        this.clients = [];
    }
}

var connections = new HashMap();
const json = new jsonparse();

const wss = new websock.Server({ port: 36245 });

process.on('SIGINT',function () {
    console.log("Recieved SIGINT, stopping gracefully...");
    wss.clients.forEach(function (ws) {
        console.log("-Ended connection with "+ws.upgradeReq.socket.remoteAddress+" (1001)");
        ws.closeReasonCode = 1001;
        ws.close();
    });
    process.exit(1);
});

wss.on('connection',function connection(ws,conn) {
   console.log("+Recieved connection from "+ws._socket.remoteAddress);
   ws.upgradeReq = conn;
   ws.hasHandshook = false;
   ws.onmessage = function message(msg) {
       var message;
       try {
           message = JSON.parse(msg.data);
       } catch (ex) {
           ws.send("{\"e\":\"Invalid json.\"}");
           return;
       }
       if (!ws.hasHandshook) {
           ws.hasHandshook = true;
           if (message.type === "client") {
               //ensure code was provided and has a room
               if (typeof message.code === 'undefined' || !connections.has(message.code)) {
                   ws.send("{\"e\":\"Invalid game code.\"}");
                   ws.closeReasonCode = 4001;
                   ws.closeDescription = "Invalid game code.";
                   console.log("-Ended connection with "+ws._socket.remoteAddress+ " (4001)");
                   ws.close();
               }
               if (typeof message.name === 'undefined') {
                   //TODO error out, no player name provided
               }
               //attach client to game session
               ws.clientType = "client";
               ws.gameCode = message.code;
               ws.playerName =
               connections.get(message.code).clients.add(ws);
               ws.send("{\"joingame\":\"true\"}");
           } else {
               ws.send("{\"e\":\"Invalid type provided on handshake message.\"}");
               ws.closeReasonCode = 4000;
               ws.closeDescription = "Invalid type provided on handshake message.";
               console.log("-Ended connection with "+ws._socket.remoteAddress+" (4000)");
               ws.close();
           }
       }
   };
   ws.onclose = function close() {
       console.log("-Ended connection with "+ws.upgradeReq.socket.remoteAddress+" (Client Closed)");
   }
});
```

Client Code, which is successfully run on the press of a button on the page:

```
function DoJoinGame () {
    console.log("Button pressed!");
    gameCode = document.getElementById('base-gameCode').value.toUpperCase();
    playerName = document.getElementById('base-playerName').value;
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:36245");
    ws.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log("Connection Established!");
        ws.send("{\"type\":\"client\",\"code\":\""+gameCode+"\",\"name\":\""+playerName+"\"");
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
        let message = JSON.parse(msg.data);
        if (message.joingame) { //if this is a "client added to session" message, set display: none; on the codeEntry div
            document.getElementById('codeEntry').style.display = "none";
        }
        //TODO handle message
    };
    ws.onclose = function (evt) {
        console.log("Connection lost! ("+evt.code+":"+evt.reason+")");
    };
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed. I was attempting to connect to a non secure websocket server from a secure origin and chrome & co. wasn't a fan.